# Excel - data validation based off filtered column

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, vlookup

I have two sheets, one setup as a data (available values), and another working sheet.

Working Sheet:

[image: Working Sheet]

Data Sheet

[image]

So using data-validation, I pull in all columns A1:Z1 in data sheet into a drop down list in working sheet B3. Depending on the chosen area, I then want to populate the sub area drop down with the associated column rows.

So in this case, 'Fruit' is chosen, therefore drop down should display values from 'Data!A3:A'

Any ideas on automating this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create Named Ranges for each of your categories:

[image]

Then, for the Data Validation that changes depending on what category you choose, you will create a new List Data Validation, using a formula:

```
=INDIRECT($B$3)
```

[image]

Then, as you change `B3`, the list will update.  **Note** Without VBA (as far as I know you can't do with a formula), changing `B3` will *not* update the choice in C3. You still have to manually change that, but the list will indeed update.

[image]

Edit: If you have 26 columns with data, all different sizes, you can use VBA to create named ranges for those.